# What is Route, where and how to define it?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

I have several modules in my zend application. On one of the view script of my modules, I created a URL as such

```
$links['create'] = $this -> url(array("controller" => "roles", "action" => "create"), "custom");
```

This brings an error, saying Route "custom" is not define.

What is Route? Where to define it and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my bootstrap file i have initialized my routing by adding following function

```
public function _initRouting() {

        // Get Front Controller Instance
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

        // Get Router
        $router = $front->getRouter();
        $routedetialevent = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            '/events/detail/:id',
            array(
                'controller' => 'events',
                'action'     => 'detail'
            )
        );
        $routeregister = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            '/index/register/:id',
            array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action'     => 'register'
            )
        );

        $routerdetail = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            '/commentaries/details/:id',
            array(
                'controller' => 'commentaries',
                'action'     => 'details'
            )
        );


        $router->addRoute('post', $routedetialevent);
        $router->addRoute('register', $routeregister);
        $router->addRoute('detail', $routerdetail);
    }
```

as i have added the custom route in my events, commentaries whenever i visit detail page i dont have to write id in my url so my url will be like

http://localhost/example/events/detail/3

If i wouldnt have added route than my url would be like

http://localhost/example/events/detail/id/3

Answer (score 1):

The Zend Framework manual has pretty decent [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) about routes and the router, including descriptions of several ways to define routes.

At a very basic level, routes are used both to parse URLs into parameters (like which controller and action should be used), and to do the reverse: take parameters and produce a URL.

For your purposes, unless you want to change *how* ZF will build your URL, you can just drop the "custom" part off of your `url` call.

Comment: The documentation is not focused on beginners like me.